# General Network Error accessing SQL Server 2005 from Access 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access

We are encountering problem in using Access 2000 (.ADP) as our front-end and SQL 2005 as our back-end and we have more then 50 users:

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.

It was working fine for the last years, but now the system keeps kicking out the user. They always receive an error "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]General network error. Check your network documentation."
Any idea why is this happening or what is the best solution that we can do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check your network documentation? Or otherwise consider it as a possible network problem?

Comment: It sure looks like a network problem.

Comment: It could be a DNS issue. I've seen some weird errors with ODBC to SQL Server that turned out to be DNS problems. In one case, the client workstations were using the ISP's DNS servers and were thus having trouble resolving the SQL Server name. When they were changed to use the local domain controller as DNS, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Kicking out the user after it connects to the server? Does it happen randomly, or after a certain operation? Does the server even sees the connect attempt (Profiler connect events)?
Check out the SQL Server LOG folder on your server. See if you find any .mdmp files, or files named sqldump*. Also look into the ERRORLOG file(s) and see if you find any message that can be correlated with the moment when the client receives that error.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a user profile problem.  I've experienced this problem when the user was a member of a vast amount of groups.  Removed some groups and hey presto it worked.  Not a very descriptive error message though it could mean anything.

Cleaning up any unrequired groups may help.